# SQL dependency can not call onchange function

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, signalr

When using `SqlDependancy`, when I create a new database, it works well, but the time I use it with an existing database, although I enable the broker service, and the `SqlDependancy.Start` works normally, the `OnChange` function is not called the time change data in the database. HELP!!!

Comment: You might want to tag the SQL database engine you’re using. SQL itself has no concept of brokers or anything

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, the case is that, i create a new database and enable broker service, the time i change the data inside the table, i am notified, but then i do the same thing to the other database which contains multi tables, the on change function is not called automatically.

Comment: Again, please tag the database engine you’re using. Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL? DB2? SQLite? SQL Server? MariaDB? Something else?

Comment: As Sami already said: which database product are you using? But probably just as important: which programming language?

Comment: sql server, with asp.net, signalR